# What is the quickest way to collapse cells that are the same word but capitalized differently?

Tags: r

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
> dput(df$value)
c("Positive", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", "Negative", 
"Negative", "Negative", "negative", "Negative", "Negative", "NEGATIVE", 
"Negative", "Negative", "Positive", "POSITIVE", "Negative", "Negative")
```

I want to group the `Negative`, `negative`, and `NEGATIVE` together

and also group the `POSITIVE` and `Positive` together.

What is a quick way to do this?

Comment: Create a copy of the vector and convert to all upper- or lower-case (with `toupper` or `tolower`) and group on the copy.

Comment: Follow @Limey suggestion, also show us what is your expected output so we can give a more specific answer to you.